# Accessing config module from sub directory

Tags: node.js, express, configuration, config, backend

Has anyone used node config module to manage configurations? My configurations are working fine when I'm running it from main.js, my main js file. But when I'm trying to access the configuration files from a sub directory, it is showing the error
throw new Error('Configuration property "' + property + '" is not defined'"

I just wanna know how can i make the configurations accessible from a sub directory?

Thanks in advance!

PS: i read the documentation but i didn't get it.

Comment: Can show some sample code?